# Can we forward a http client response made in our servlet to a client?

Tags: java, servlets, httpclient

We have a webserver streaming video, which has a secured access to its paths. After login you get a session cookie, which you have to send with further requests. On the other side we have a building control app, which should consume this streams, but can handle only path based authentication.
So my idea was to create a servlet controller in which a http client signs-in into the streaming server, establish a session and forwards a mpeg stream to its clients.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
public Response get() {
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(...);
    Response response = target.request().post(...AUTHENTICATION...)
    ...
    ...
    response = target.request().get(); //access the stream path
    ...
    return response;
}
```

If I try this pseudo-code, it fails with the first `target.request().post()` and a `NoHttpResponseException` that says, that the streaming webserver failed to respond, but the service located on another box is indeed reachable...

**Are there any restrictions for making client requests to another server within a servlet?**

And if I try this approach with `http://www.google.com` I end up in http status `406 - Not acceptable`...

**Is it generally possible to forward a response this way?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an mwe?

Comment: Minimal working example

Comment: I've created this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/christian-raedel/9dfbff3de0223b403ee4), but it's not really a *working* example to you, because the streaming server requires a license.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward such a request in the following manner:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
public void get(HttpServletResponse response) {
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(...);
    Response authResponse = target.request().post(...AUTHENTICATION...)
    ...
    ...
    Response clientResponse = target.request().get();
    try {
        InputStream input = clientResponse.readEntity(InputStream.class);
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        int next;
        while((next = input.read()) != -1) {
            output.write(next);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```